# How to make an unofficial Orange Pi 5 Mipi-DSI display work on an Orange Pi 5 Arch Linux system, given kernel driver source and .deb package?

Tags: arch-linux, linux-kernel, raspberry-pi, kernel-modules, display

For a while I've tried to make use of a display I ordered from Aliexpress to make it work with [an unofficial 7Ji Arch Linux distribution for Orange Pi 5](https://github.com/7Ji/orangepi5-archlinuxarm), to no avail. Perhaps against my better judgement, I prefered that distribution over OPi's original Arch one because I wanted a barebones Arch that would still natively work well on OPi5, and that it does, besides the display thing. The display is [5" 4-lane DSI, model "WKS50HD005"](https://aliexpress.com/item/1005006330495611.html), if that's of use.

I'd known that firstly I need to enable dtbo overlay for OPi5's frontal lcd2 port, and after a bit found it's specified via `FDTOVERLAYS` entry in `/boot/extlinux/extlinux.conf`, pointing to a .dtbo file `/boot/dtbs/linux-aarch64-orangepi5/rockchip/overlay/`, but enabling the builtin *rk3588-lcd2.dtbo* overlay only backlit the display. So up to this point I've been trying to make it work day in day out... for a few days.

The display's store page provided a link to [drivers on Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12tf1jnMa_VAKAdOYp4VAlMFsPj7Kt1BK/view), with an Orange Pi 5 directory among others, consisting of a .deb package, *panel-innolux-afj101-ba2131.c* kernel module and a *readme.txt*. The readme.txt had instructions to compile the kernel from [original source on Baidu](https://pan.baidu.com/s/1n6WX0YF8YLShxFFPb4EPjQ?pwd=WKS6) (link was later given by seller, but *I have no account there* so couldn't download anything).

First I thought that simply installing the .deb with Arch's dpkg will work, but bricked the system (later found out the package wrote into a *different* /lib/modules/ kernel directory than that of my kernel), although in itself it was a non-issue as I just reflashed the Arch image to the NVMe drive I booted from, with a backup SDcard flashed with OPi's Arch installation. For reference, .deb's kernel is ver. `5.10.110` vs 7Ji's Arch kernel ver. `5.10.110-6`, hence I still assume there should be some compatibility.

I later considered I need to compile provided .c module, so I pulled kernel along with headers from [7Ji repo](https://github.com/7Ji/archrepo/releases/tag/aarch64), made a Makefile and compiled it, with *panel-innolux-afj101-ba2131.ko* file being outputted to `/lib/modules/5.10.110-6-aarch64-orangepi5+/kernel/drivers/gpu/drm/panel/`. I also added a `kernel/drivers/gpu/drm/panel/panel-innolux-afj101-ba2131.ko` (*as per readme.txt*) line to both *modules.order* and a new `/etc/modules-load.d/` .conf file, still to no avail.

Then I decided to unpack the .deb file and found almost nothing: there wasn't a `/kernel/drivers/gpu/` directory, let alone the module, even though *modules.builtin* contained lines:

> kernel/drivers/gpu/drm/panel/panel-simple.ko
> kernel/drivers/gpu/drm/panel/panel-innolux-afj101-ba2131.ko

From .deb, I found a *rk3588-lcd2.dtbo* file, in `lib/modules/linux-image-legacy-rockchip-rk3588/rockchip/overlay`, of all places, albeit in directory similar to 7Ji's Arch builtin `/boot/dtbs/linux-aarch64-orangepi5/rockchip/overlay` -- file being different from my builtin one, so I tried putting it alongside the originally builtin *rk3588-lcd2.dtbo* and linking *extlinux.conf* to it. As a result, display hadn't even backlit.

Grepping "*dsi*" from dmesg *with builtin dtbo* shows:

> [    7.606294] dw-mipi-dsi2 fde30000.dsi: [drm:dw_mipi_dsi2_bind] *ERROR* Failed to find panel or bridge: -517
> [    8.530159] rockchip-drm display-subsystem: bound fde30000.dsi (ops 0xffffffc0111897e0)
> [    9.151023] dw-mipi-dsi2 fde30000.dsi: [drm:dw_mipi_dsi2_encoder_enable] final DSI-Link bandwidth: 403300 x 4 Kbps

*further grepping "*display-subsystem*":

> [    7.594906] rockchip-drm display-subsystem: failed to get
> hdmi0_phy_pll: -517
> [    7.594916] rockchip-drm display-subsystem: failed to get hdmi1_phy_pll: -2
> [    7.606247] rockchip-drm display-subsystem: bound fdd90000.vop (ops 0xffffffc01117f730)
> [    8.510393] rockchip-drm display-subsystem: failed to get hdmi0_phy_pll: -517
> [    8.510408] rockchip-drm display-subsystem: failed to get hdmi1_phy_pll: -2
> [    8.530061] rockchip-drm display-subsystem: bound fdd90000.vop (ops 0xffffffc01117f730)
> [    8.530159] rockchip-drm display-subsystem: bound fde30000.dsi (ops 0xffffffc0111897e0)
> [    8.531866] rockchip-drm display-subsystem: failed to parse loader memory
> [    9.262777] rockchip-drm display-subsystem: [drm] fb0: rockchipdrmfb frame buffer device
> [    9.264376] [drm] Initialized rockchip 3.0.0 20140818 for display-subsystem on minor 0

Whereas doing so *with .deb-provided dtbo*:

> [    7.606818] dw-mipi-dsi2 fde20000.dsi: [drm:dw_mipi_dsi2_bind] *ERROR* Failed to find panel or bridge: -517
> [    9.139902] dw-mipi-dsi2 fde20000.dsi: [drm:dw_mipi_dsi2_encoder_enable] final DSI-Link bandwidth: 414000 x 4 Kbps

Unwillingly I have to wonder if my kernel won't aggree to make my current dream of having a working Mipi-DSI display a reality -- I'm helped by the fact that pointing original OPi5's Arch's `FDTOVERLAYS` to its respective *rk3588-lcd2.dtbo* also only backlights the display. Though... it doesn't really help, considering it's *not working*. I'm not very experienced working with Linux kernel, nor its modules, but I very much would appreciate any and all help and knowledge I can get to make this project work, and in general. I'll also make sure to provide all additional info that might be useful.

Big thanks to anyone who'd considered this question worthy of their attention, in advance.
(PS. no orange-pi tag, hence #raspberry-pi)